# Append a <span> within each occurrence of <figure> in a block of HTML using PHP

Tags: php

I'm working in PHP with a block of text roughly like this:

```
$html = '
    <p>Paragraph one</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="image1.jpg">
    </figure>
    <p>Paragraph two</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Paragraph three</p>
';
```

Within this block I want to append a span just before each occurrence of the closing figure tag, so that the HTML looks like this:

```
<p>Paragraph one</p>
<figure>
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <span>Text within span</span>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph two</p>
<figure>
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    <span>Text within span</span>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph three</p>
```

I'm unsure how to proceed from here (or if this is in fact the most obvious way to proceed):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('figure') as $element ){
    //append <span>Text within span</span> before closing </figure>
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$html = '
    <p>Paragraph one</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="image1.jpg">
    </figure>
    <p>Paragraph two</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Paragraph three</p>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('figure') as $element) {
    $span = $doc->createElement('span');
    $span->textContent = 'Some text here';

    $element->appendChild($span);
}

$html = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```